# Exclude non-null properties when serializing a Kotlin data class

Tags: kotlin

I often will create a data class in Kotlin that is used internally for data models. Example:

```
data class MyDataModel(
    var id: String? = null,
    var ownerId: String,
    var name: String,
    var isPrivate: Boolean = false,
)
```

I often need to serialize these classes to JSON. The problem is that some of the class properties are not nullable and there are cases where I need to exclude those fields in the serialization. I haven't found a clean and simple way to do that. The solution I currently use is not to use non-nullable properties and then set those that I don't want serialized to null.

Is there another approach?

Comment: what are you using for serialization/deserialization? There are multiple approaches to this that depend on that.

Comment: Gson. Kotlin also has its own serialization but it really isn't ripe at this stage. I don't need deserialization. Just serialization.

Comment: In that case I would recommend using one of the ways that are presented here https://www.baeldung.com/gson-exclude-fields-serialization

Comment: I'm aware of that solution. Overly complex just to get a null serialization.

Comment: @Alex It should also be pointed out that the sample code you linked to shows this:
field.getName().equals("otherVerboseInfo") - Using hardcoded strings to refer to your properties is really bad, especially when it comes to renaming your properties.

Comment: The hardcoded property string is bad, but it is present in one of the versions, not all. I can't provide a better answer for gson since I use jackson, where all you would need to do is to annotate the field you want to be ignored with @JsonIgnore.

Comment: What do you mean by "use non-nullable properties and then set those that I don't want serialized to null"? It's not possible to set non-nullable properties to null. Or are you talking about `null` in the JSON? You want to exclude the non-nullable properties, or the nullable properties that are null?

Comment: @Alex I could switch to Jackson. So are you saying that with Jackson you only need to annotate the property and nothing more? And this works with Kotlin?

Comment: @AdamMillerchip I'm talking about ignoring non-nullable fields during serialization. Those fields must not appear in the JSON.

Comment: Yes, it works with kotlin, and yes, you only need add @JsonIgnore. We use jackson because it comes with spring (almost all of our services are in kotlin). You would need to use the jackson-module-kotlin (it is in the main maven repo). The thing is, I don't know the rest of your code to know if jackson would be better than gson in every aspect, but at least in this particular case, it is much more easier. You can see here on number 7 https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not (btw, I am not affiliated with baeldung)

Answer (score 0):

Solution using [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization):

1. Define class, including all fields you want to be serialized, mark it as `@Serializable`

```kotlin
@Serializable
open class MyDataModelSerializable(
    open var id: String? = null
)
```

2. Make your data class to be its subtype:

```kotlin
data class MyDataModel(
    var ownerId: String,
    var name: String,
    var isPrivate: Boolean = false,
    override var id: String? = null
) : MyDataModelSerializable(id)
```

3. Serialize instances of `MyDataModel` class with serializer for `MyDataModelSerializable`:

```kotlin
val s = serializer<MyDataModelSerializable>()
println(Json.encodeToString(s, MyDataModel(ownerId = "1", name = "2", id = "3", isPrivate = true))) //{"id":"3"}
println(Json.encodeToString(s, MyDataModel(ownerId = "1", name = "2", isPrivate = true))) //{}
println(Json{encodeDefaults = true}.encodeToString(s, MyDataModel(ownerId = "1", name = "2"))) //{"id":null}
```

Comment: But that serializes the entire class. Nothing that Gson doesn't already do. Also, the output you showed for the first item shows only the id, yet the name and ownerId are not null and should be serialized as well.

Comment: But that was your original requirment - to not serialize a non-nullable fields. Maybe you confuse them? Nullable references are the one that can hold null (like `String?`), non-nullable - are those that can not (like `String`).

Comment: If you need the opposite - to exclude nullable types, it is even easier, you don't need any auxilary classes, just mark you original data class as `@Serializable`, and nullable fields as `@Transient`

Comment: Also the serialization library doesn't encode default values, so if you just don't want properties with a ``null`` value appearing, give them that as a default (like in your example, ``var id: String? = null``) and it will only be included if it's set to a non-null value. I agree that it's not exactly clear what you want though, might be worth reading through the guide intro and seeing if it fits what you're trying to do: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/basic-serialization.md#defaults-are-not-encoded